# how to replace text in the body using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to replace all instances of "onAppDeactivate" with "onAppActivate"  in the entire body of the document, but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Any ideas?

```
var pageSource = document.body.getElementsByTagName("script");

var replaceWithThis = "onAppActivate";
for(var i=0, l=pageSource.length; i<l; i++)
{
    pageSource[i].innerHTML.replace(/onAppDeactivate/gi, replaceWithThis)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace text in a script file or script block that has already been parsed.  It won't do anything.

You can replace entire functions in your javascript by actually assigning new code to the function name in javascript (not with text manipulation).

For example, if there was a function already defined:

```
function foo() {
   // do something
}
```

You, could replace that with your own function:

```
function foo() {
   // do something different
}
```

---

In your pastebin code, you can disable the onBlur() and onFocus() global functions by running this code after the original code in the page runs.

```
window.onBlur = window.onFocus = function() {};
```

Comment: that might work actually how would i go about doing that? My plans are to make this into a chrome extension.

Comment: What exactly you would do here depends on what you're trying to accomplish and what the script looks like that you're trying to modify.  Without a thorough understanding of both, I can't advise more specifically.

Comment: this is the code that is loaded on teh webpage http://pastebin.com/Kc3igC10 and i want to make onblur and onfocus = null

Comment: After reading your pastebin code, I added more to the end of my answer.

Comment: i had no luck with your new addition maybe this would help clear things up http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/116361